# Email2Case not populating Origin/RT *Already tried all permissions*

Tags: email2case

So I've seen a ton of answers for this, but none of them seem to fit my scenario.

We have Email2Case setup, with about 75 email to case addresses.  Almost all of them work flawlessly, assigning the Origin and Record Type.

However, a few just don't update the case at all.  The case gets created, but with just a normal Record Type and origin.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

What logic are you using to assign the record types?  Have you checked for spelling mistakes (additional or missing spaces)?  Are you using workflow rules?  Perhaps you can try focusing just on those that don't work and turn off the other email addresses.  Open up the filters to see if the Email2Case works at the simplest level, then add in your other filters and see at which point it 'falls over'.